# Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index

Tags: python

```
class Solution(object):
    def searchInsert(self, nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: int
    """

        print target
        print nums
        for i in nums:
            print i
            if i==target:
                return nums.index(i)

            else:
                 if i>=target:
                    nums.append('target')-----[1](How to append the target here 
                                                   before the 'i' element to which 
                                                   compared)

                    else:
                        nums.append('target')

                print False
```

Given a sorted array and a target value, return the index. If not, return the index where it would be if it were inserted in order ?

My question  here is:- If  target is different then how do I append the target before the ith element in the list ? ( which I have explicitly mentioned with [1] in the question)

Comment: I am not understanding what you want to append. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sounds like you want `list.insert`.  `nums.insert(index, element)` will insert `element` into `nums` at `index`. Everything at and after `index` will get moved right one position.

Comment: I have edited the question @TeodoricoLevoff

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the functions in the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) module.  They handle both hits and misses.